# Boolean modifier flickering between difference and union?

Tags: modifiers

So I am creating an animation for a drill string for an oilfield representation and when I set the drill string (cylinder) to follow the bezier curve for an animation and then set a Boolean modifier on the ground (cube) the cylinder flickers from difference to union as if its trying to use both options at once, I have tried inverting and resetting normal's and removing doubles but no doubles were found and the normal's didn't fix the issue. I cant find a way to upload my .blend file so ill try to use pictures best I can. The first picture is the path of the drill string. The second picture is the Boolean modifier working properly. The third picture is the Boolean modifier not working properly and it flashes between these two. Any help or solution is welcome, thanks.
[image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: The dimensions of the models are quite large. Does scaling them by less than 0.01 and bringing them near the origin help?

Comment: Unfortunately it made it worse so I made a new file all together and it still didn't work ad I am having the same problem.

Comment: Did you try to move the curve slightly away from the plane? Another idea is enabling Full Filling at the curve's properties.

Comment: Yes I tried moving the curve slightly off the face and it did not work but something I have noticed on the new smaller version is that it only glitches during a certain segment of the animation, I will add another screenshot and indicate where it is glitching, I tried making the curve smoother and that didn't help.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't spot the issue in the last picture. Can you please share the blend file?

Comment: How do I share the blend file. I tried to find a way earlier but couldn't.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/help/

Comment: The file has been added below the pictures.